# Vertical space before environments

Tags: spacing, environments

How can I control the vertical space before an environment, e.g., `tabular` or `minipage`?

Here is an example that reproduces my problem:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
    \noindent TEXT-A\vspace{5pt}\\   TEXT-B\\TEXT-C
    \\[2em]
    \noindent TEXT-D\vspace{5pt}\\   \begin{tabular}{@{}l}TEXT-E\\TEXT-F \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

The spacing between `TEXT-A` and `TEXT-B` is different from the spacing between `TEXT-D` and `TEXT-E`:

[image]

I have learned so far that the space between `TEXT-D` and `TEXT-E` is normal if I delete `\\TEXT-F`:

[image]

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Inserting vertical space by `\vspace{5pt}\\` is not a good way. It does not end the paragraph, `\\` just breaks the line. And consider a line break *after* vertical whitespace - which line should be broken then?

Instead of `\\` use a blank line or write `\par` to end the paragraph. A line break will be a consequence as well. After the paragraph break you may insert vertical space. Perhaps `\smallskip`, `\medskip` or `\bigskip` could be a good idea. I don't like it to manually  distribute a lot of spaces (some points here, some there) through the document. If you later desire to stretch or to shrink a bit, you would have to adjust at many places. Better use macros or lengths for that, which could be adjusted in the preamble.

Back to the main problem.

- Some environments insert vertical space before. For example displayed formulas insert certain space (`\abovedisplayskip` or `abovedisplayshortskip`), list environments like `itemize`, `enumerate` and `description` but also `center` and `quote` insert space of the length `\topsep`. Such spaces could be adjusted, but it depends on the environment.
- If you use a class which tries to fill up the page, like the book class, vertical space could be inserted for this purpose. You could try the command `\raggedbottom` just to see the effect without that vertical justification.
- In the case of `tabular` and `minispace`, add the optional argument `[t]` for top alignment:

  `\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l} ...`

We could speak about further details if you post a small compilable example which shows the problem. If you didn't manage it yet: don't try to reproduce starting from scratch. Instead take a copy of your document, and reduce it step by step, compile each step o ensure it's still showing the problem. This way you would get a demonstration example.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, I have been able to reproduce the problem, see above...

Comment: @Frank: in this case adding an optional parameter [t] for top alignment of the table would be sufficient. I'll add that to my answer.

Comment: That's right. Based on previous trouble with vertical alignment and glue, I have blamed the wrong thing. Many thanks!

Comment: `[t]` worked for me! I don't understand why though.